# HackerRank leaderboard challenge

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, sorting, time-limit-exceeded

I have been doing [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard) challenge in which I need to determine and return one's (i.e. `alice`) rank on a leaderboard by comparing her scores to the others'. I made this work in all but this one case where there are 200000 scores on the board, so I believe my program is not effective at large scale. I am receiving a timeout error. I tried to shorten the program as much as possible but I think loops are still too much of a problem. I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector <int> climbingLeaderboard(vector <int> scores, vector <int> alice) {
    vector<int> result;
    reverse(alice.begin(), alice.end());
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int lastRank = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < alice.size(); i++) {

        int rank = lastRank;
        for (int j = lastIndex; j < scores.size(); j++) {
            if (alice[i] >= scores[j]) {
                lastIndex = j;
                break;
            }

            else if (alice[i] < scores[j]) {
                rank++;
            }

            if (scores[j] == scores[j+1] && rank != 1) {
                rank--;
            }
        }
        result.push_back(rank);   
        lastRank = rank;
    }
    reverse(result.begin(), result.end());

    return result;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> scores(n);
    for(int scores_i = 0; scores_i < n; scores_i++){
       cin >> scores[scores_i];
    }
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    vector<int> alice(m);
    for(int alice_i = 0; alice_i < m; alice_i++){
       cin >> alice[alice_i];
    }
    vector <int> result = climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice);
    for (ssize_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        cout << result[i] << (i != result.size() - 1 ? "\n" : "");
    }
    cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Input**

```
7
100 100 50 40 40 20 10
4
5 25 50 120
```

**Sample Output**

```
6
4
2
1
```

**Explanation**

The second row of input is composed of the scores on the leaderboard and the fourth row contains the scores of Alice. The score she gets during each attempt is compared with other scores on the leaderboard to determine her rank. [Dense Ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Dense_ranking_.28.221223.22_ranking.29) is used here. So from the sample input, the first two `100`s on the leaderboard rank 1st and then `50` ranks the 2nd, both `40`s rank 3rd and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### don't use `using namespace std`

You should not use `using namespace std` because it eliminates some important information, which may lead to some conflicts with your classes or classes of other libraries. It is not uncommon to have a `vector` class, which has a totally other meaning than the `std::vector`. And to be honest, it isn't that much more work, to type `std::` in front of the classes/functions, is it?

### use `std algorithms`

You do everything with for loops, which is bloated and error prone. Use the algorithms of the `std` namespace instead. I provide you with a short an clean example, how you could do the above task (and more) with less lines.

### your algorithm itself

You should think about logical improvements. Is it necessary to store every score in a vector, when equal scores produce the same rankings, and the following scores just increments by one? Therefore I took the `std::unique` algorithm, which returns a `forward iterator`. `std::unique` doesn't erase anything itself. It just moves duplicates to the end of the range (our `std::vector`); you have to `erase` them manually.
But, before you can use `std::unique` you have to order your elements. I don't know if it's guaranteed to get the score input in a descending order; thus I simply use `std::sort` to ensure this.
After that, it's a simple `std::lower_bound` (which is a binary search instead a linear search) to get the first iterator to an element, which is not less than the provided score (ok, I had to pass an other function object, because we want to check for greater and not for less).
`Iterators` starts with a zero index. This means, we have to add 1 to our index, to get the official ranking.
Easy, huh?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> scores { 100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10 };
    std::vector<int> aliceScores { 5, 25, 50, 120 };
    // sort and erase duplicates
    std::sort(std::begin(scores), std::end(scores), std::greater<int>());
    scores.erase(std::unique(std::begin(scores), std::end(scores)), std::end(scores));

    // just a lambda to make the output part more readable
    auto locateRanking = [](const auto& _scores, int _newScore){
        auto itr = std::lower_bound(std::begin(_scores), std::end(_scores), _newScore, std::greater<int>());
        return std::distance(std::begin(_scores), itr) + 1;
    };

    // output part
    for (auto newScore : aliceScores)
    {
        std::cout << locateRanking(scores, newScore) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

### tl;dr

Sort the `vector`, remove the duplicates and use a binary search instead of your linear approach and you will discover a huge performance benefit.

Comment: You also gain a lot by using `std::lower_bound`, which does a binary search instead of a linear search.

Comment: This just showed how little I knew of this language, amazing! Actually I've tried to save some work by breaking the loop at a certain point during the search and by also starting the search from where previous loop left so that it wouldn't read the entire vector again, but it still wasn't enough. I'll try this tomorrow and get back with the result, thanks! (btw the input is always in descending order since it's a leaderboard)

Comment: If you would know, that the scores of alice are also in a specific order, you could improve it.  As you are already suggesting, you could store the index from the last search and start with the new one. But, this is a task, you can solve by your own ;)

Comment: I tried to implement this, removed duplicates from the vector and then run the loops, but still got timeout error. I then wanted to implement the second part hoping that it would work that way but could not fully understand it. Could you please elaborate on `locateRanking()`part, how things work there?

Comment: I just want to point out a common misunderstanding. `std::unique` doesn't move duplicates to the end of the range. The only data movement is non-duplicates toward the front of the range. The elements after the new logical end have unspecified values.

Comment: @omnimiratus I tried it myself on the website, and I got a 100% score on the website with almost the same code. Unfortunately it is just a C++11 compiler, but this code did the job. https://pastebin.com/rNNbm5QQ

Comment: I don't like copying code so I was just trying to understand and implement things my way, but the second part of the code where you used `std::lower_bound` and `std::distance` was a bit unclear (or perhaps too complicated for me) especially since I'm not familiar with C++11, so I just kindly asked for elaboration on it :)) But it's fine, I'll try to sort it out myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok. `std::lower_bound` returns an iterator to the first element, which doesn't fits in the passed functor. In fact, we searched for a value, which is NOT `std::greater` than the passed value (alice score). That's it. That's the magic. `std::distance` just calculates the difference from the begin iterator to the iterator found by `std::lower_bound`. If it's the first value, the difference is 0. But we need the first element to be 1, thus we simply add 1 to the difference. Hopefully it's clearer now ;)

Comment: crystal clear, I truly appreciate it! :))

Answer (score 1):

One strategy: Do binary split of `scores`, and for each split, keep track of the smallest number of `alice` that is greater than or equal to the largest element of each branch and the largest number of `alice` smaller than the smallest element of the branch. Once those two numbers are adjacent, don't split that branch any more. So, taking your example `scores = 100 100 50 40 40 20 10` `alice = 5 25 50 120`. I'll split `scores`, with `alice` scores in brackets surrounding each branch in bold.

At iteration 0, I have

{[120]**( 100 100 50 40 40 20 10 )**[5]}

That is, I haven't done any splits, so everything is in the same branch. The largest number of the branch is 100, and the smallest number of `alice` larger than that is 120, so 120 goes on the left of the branch. The smallest number of the branch is 10, and the largest `alice` number smaller than that is 5, so 5 goes on the right.

In iteration 1, I have:

{[120]**(100 100 50 40)**[25]} {[50]**(40 20 10)**[5]}

iteration 2:

{[120]**(100 100)**[50]}{[50]**(50 40)**[25]} {[50]**(40 20 10)**[5]}

Since there are no numbers in `alice` between 120 and 50, the first branch is done splitting. Since there are no numbers between 50 and 25, the second branch is also done. So the next iteration moves on to the third branch:

{[120]**(100 100)**[50]}{[50]**(50 40)**[25]} {[50]**(40 20)**[5]} {[25]**(10)**[5]}

Iteration 4:

{[120]**(100 100)**[50]}{[50]**(50 40)**[25]} ]} {[50]**(40)**[25]}{[25]**(20)**[5]} {[25]**(10)**[5]}

At this point, I’ve done all the splits I can, and I can just read off the ranks; each rank of a number from `alice` is the count of distinct members from `scores` to the left of the first instance of it, plus one. 120 is all the way to the left, so its rank is 1. The first instance of 50 has one distinct element of `scores` to the left of it, so its score is 2. And so on.

The dense ranking requirement means that you'll have to get rid of duplicate members, but other than that this algorithm should be logarithmic time, rather than linear time for your algorithm.